# Passing cryptoStream and generics to a WebMethod in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cryptography

I have data on following variables.

```
CryptoStream searialNumber = encryptedSearialNumber;
Dictionary<string, object> x= userInput;
Dictionary<string, object> y= hardwareInfo;
```

I want to pass these as parameters to a `WebMethod` of an ASP.NET XML (asmx) web service. I know I can't pass these parameters without changing them to appropriate data types. Because they can't be serialized.

Can any one please suggest a standard way to pass these parameters to a web method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering why this question is only viewed at 33 times.I am sure at least 20 times i clicked the question to find Whether some one answered.is some thing wrong with my question?Any way i solved the issue with a different approach.

Changed the `Cryptostream to bytes` by passed it to a `MemoryStrem`also created `custom serialize classes` to replace the dictionaries and Passed those to web method.

Comment: Your own clicks probably don't count for views. Or probably not more than once, anyway.